# How to find the utilization of the hardware performance counters for a specific function (block of code) in python?

Tags: python, performance, hardware, perf

Problem:
I want to measure the hardware performance counters (IPC, branch misprediction, cache miss rate, memory bandwidth, TLB miss, communication performance between CPU and GPU) for a specific part of code in an algorithm training on CPU-GPU. Is there any metric that I can use to find out the utilization of these counters?

*Also, Is it possible with perf to collect hardware performance statistics for only part of a python program's execution?*

Note: I initially checked performance-features from pip, but could not find the necessary perf counters I needed from the above list mentioned. Can someone let me know if there is any metric that I can use to calculate the utilization of perf counters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[PAPI](https://icl.utk.edu/papi/)** is certainly what you are looking for. It is a relatively portable performance API to get information about hardware counters. It is available from Python using the package [python_papi](https://pypi.org/project/python_papi/). PAPI enable you to analyse only a given part of a program (be defining the section using start-stop annotations). It also [supports GPUs](https://icl.utk.edu/files/print/2022/exa-papi-2022-ecp-poster.pdf) as well. To start with, you can read [this research paper](https://icl.utk.edu/files/publications/2020/icl-utk-1408-2020.pdf) about it. Good luck for your PhD.